# Disable Plone Archetypes index/convert doc/pdf files

Tags: python, plone, zope, archetypes, plone-3.x

If I rebuild my catalog in plone I get many of these infos:

```
2010-02-18T11:26:09 INFO Archetypes Error while trying to convert file contents to 'text/plain' in <Field file(file:rw)>.getIndexable() of <ATFile at /site/test1/test.doc>: Unable to find binary "wvHtml" in /sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin
```

This happens to .doc and .pdf files.

I don't want to convert docs or PDFs. How can I disable it completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable (remove) transforms in ZMI/portal_transforms tool. If Plone does not find transform from Word to plain text or PDF to plain text, it won't try to index the file contents.
Go to ZMI/portal_transforms and remove word_to_html item.

Answer (score 2):

It is trying to index your doc/pdf files by converting them to HTML files first. Just install wv(ware). The message will go away and all your DOC & PDF files will be indexed and show up in your searches.

On Ubuntu/Debian: sudo apt-get install wv

Is there a reason you don't want to index PDFs or Word documents?

Comment: We have to many doc / pdf files in this portal. Right now we dont wont it in searches.

Possible to disable this converting completely?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't wanna convert docs or pdfs. How can i disable it completly? [sic]

Well, you're currently not indexing them, so there's nothing to change.

The above message is an INFO message, it's not an error.  If you don't want to see these in your event log, you can change the event-log-level in your buildout configuration or your zope.conf

from the docs:

```
event-log-level
  Set the level of the console output for the event log. Level may be any of
  CRITICAL, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, or ALL. Defaults to INFO.
```